# Change default filesystem root

Tags: boot, filesystem

I have an external hard drive that I want to set as the filesystem root but boot from an SD card. How would I do this?

I've copied the filesystem to the partition, and tried updating config.txt with `root=UUID={UUID}` and cmdline.txt with `root=UUID={UUID}`. However, it still fails to start up and never completes the boot process, usually ending with kernel panic.

What am I missing?

cmdline.txt:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=UUID=96fd5e33-3220-37e9-af31-b87ea8d03dda rootfstype=hfsplus elevator=deadline rootwait rootdelay=5
```

config.txt (different than default)

```
root=UUID=96fd5e33-3220-37e9-af31-b87ea8d03dda
initramfs initrd.sda
```

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1058:259c Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04d9:0006 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lsusb -t` output:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
```

Comment: I am using a 4B. not sure about the os

Comment: @bravo I used `blkid` to determine the uuid and partuuid, and did try partuuid={partuuid}

Comment: yes. If I was doing this from scratch, what steps do I take?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132204/discussion-between-2pichar-and-bravo).

Comment: Well I've been able to mount the drive before. Could it still be a problem?

Comment: So the drive is different than most in that it has a USB 3.0 type micro b connector instead of SATA, so it connects with a micro-b to a cable.

Comment: I didn't ask about the physical characteristics as that is largely irrelevant - if you don't want to add the information I asked for (`lsusb` and `lsusb -t`) then I'll just remove my comments and wish you good luck - perhaps someone with the ability to guess what hardware you have will stumble on this and answer you

Comment: I'll do it when I get back in front of the computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by doing a couple of things. First of all, my drive had been formatted as an HFS+ drive, so I suspect that that played a factor in preventing the RPi from booting correctly, and secondly I was using the UUID instead of the PARTUUID.

What I did to make it work:

1. Repartitioned the drive to take full advantage of the space
2. Formatted the drive using `mkfs.ext4` to create a new ext4 filesystem
3. Copied the data from the SD card to the new drive with `rsync -ax`
4. Retrieved the PARTUUID via `lsblk -o NAME,PARTUUID`
5. Created an initramfs with `mkinitramfs -o initrd.sda`
6. Added `initramfs initrd.sda` to `config.txt`
7. Replaced the `root=` lines in `config.txt` and `cmdline.txt` with `root=PARTUUID=partuuid`
8. Added `rw` to `cmdline.txt` to mount filesystem as read-write and not read-only

Changes to boot files:
`config.txt`:

```
root=PARTUUID=partuuid
initramfs initrd.sda
```

`cmdline.txt`:

```
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=partuuid rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rw rootwait
```